# inclusion-exclusion problem - dinner arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I'm working on my combinatorics assignment and I don't fully understand this question:

> Suppose that a person with seven friends invites a different subset of three
>   friends to dinner every night for one week (seven days). How many ways can
>   this be done so that all friends are included at least once?

So, the answer is :
    $$P(7C3,7)-7P(6C3,7)+(7C2) \cdot P(5C3,7)$$

I get it. It's just a little detail I am missing.
Why can't I expand the equation with $-(7C3)\cdot P(4C3,7)+(7C4) \cdot P(3C3,7)$? I mean, $3$ friends are invited so for the exclusion, can't I count exclusion of $4$ friends? I'm definitely misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the equation as you suggested, but the terms you're adding are zero. Notice that $4C3<7$, and $3C3<7$, so you can't form a permutation of seven triplets if there aren't at least seven triplets to start with. OTOH $5C3$ is ten, which exceeds seven.

Comment: oh dang... thank you so much!

Comment: @SubinPark You're welcome. That's a lot of dinners :)